# refleccion de metodo en tiempo de ejecucion php

Tags: php, reflection, reflexión

Estoy buscando obtener en que linea se ejecuto un metodo en tiempo real con proposito educativo.

***por ejemplo dado el siguiente codigo:***

```
<?php
class FooClass 
{
    public function testFunction($fakeArgument)
    {
        //obtener de que archivo y linea de ese archivo fue ejecutado
        //output: test.php linea: 12
    }
}

$fooClass = new FooClass();
$fooClass->testFunction('Hola Mundo');
```

***Ejemplo de la vista en el editor:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***he intentado con esto:***

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass('FooClass');
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

Pero esto solo me retorna el archivo donde se define la clase; yo busco conocer el archivo de donde ***se invoco***;

***De que forma puedo obtener el archivo y la linea en donde se invoka le metodo?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe un método nativo listo para usar, pero si existe un método que puede darnos parte de la información [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-backtrace.php):

***Implementación:***

A. debes utilizarlo dentro del método o cadena de ejecución de los métodos para poder obtener lo que se está ejecutando hasta el momento por ejemplo:

```php
<?php

class FooClass 
{
    public function testFunction($fakeArgument)
    {
        //obtener de que archivo y linea de ese archivo fue ejecutado
        //output: test.php linea: 12
        
        $this->fakeFunction();
    }
    
    private function fakeFunction(){
        
        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    }
    
}

$fooClass = new FooClass();
$fooClass->testFunction('Hola Mundo');
```

***obtendremos una salida asi:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es un array con los dos métodos que se ejecutaron en secuencia en donde tendremos como primer elemento; el ultimo método y así sucesivamente.

Dentro del array encontraremos por método los elementos `file` y `line` que son la interrogante que tenía.

La implementación ya dependería de cada desarrollador, pero con este array navegable se obtiene lo principal que se buscaba.